# Buddypress get link from bp-members-adminbar.php

Tags: buddypress

I was wondering if it is possible to get a link from the bp-members-adminbar.php

i have found this code in the file, its the link to to my account - my profile page but i want that link to be in the website and not in the bp bar

// User Admin > Edit this user's profile

```
$wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
    'parent' => $bp->user_admin_menu_id,
    'id'     => 'edit-profile',
    'title'  => __( "Edit Profile", 'buddypress' ),
    'href'   => bp_get_members_component_link( 'profile', 'edit' )
) );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
<a href="<?php echo bp_loggedin_user_domain() ?>profile/edit">Edit Profile</a>
```

Comment: Sabrin - you're welcome - please click the checkmark to Accept the answer - that's how stackoverflow works.